# Datepicker display issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I used datepicker from http://foxrunsoftware.github.io/DatePicker/ and copied its demo,but the datepicker doesn't display. I have checked everything, but can't find out the reason..please help me ,this is my code

```
 <html>
    <title>test</title>
    <head>
    <script src="http://libs.baidu.com/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./datepicker/js/datepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./datepicker/css/base.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./datepicker/css/clean.css" />

    <script>
//this is the script code
    $('#inputDate').DatePicker({
      mode: 'single',
      position: 'right',
      onBeforeShow: function(el){
        if($('#inputDate').val())
          $('#inputDate').DatePickerSetDate($('#inputDate').val(), true);
      },
      onChange: function(date, el) {
        $(el).val((date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+date.getDate()+'/'+date.getFullYear());
        if($('#closeOnSelect input').attr('checked')) {
          $(el).DatePickerHide();
        }
      }
    });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="inputDate" class="inputDate" value="" >
        <label id="closeOnSelect" class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Close on selection</label>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Check the browser console and see if it shows any error. Also check the path of the script files that you have included.

Comment: can provide a fiddle ?

Comment: thanks John,I checked the console and it has nothing error ! The script path and file is right, so that is my problem, I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Please do initialize the Datepicker script after DOM is ready.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#inputDate').DatePicker({
      mode: 'single',
      position: 'right',
      onBeforeShow: function(el){
        if($('#inputDate').val())
          $('#inputDate').DatePickerSetDate($('#inputDate').val(), true);
      },
      onChange: function(date, el) {
        $(el).val((date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+date.getDate()+'/'+date.getFullYear());
        if($('#closeOnSelect input').attr('checked')) {
          $(el).DatePickerHide();
        }
      }
    });
   });
    </script>
```